# Right way to define vectors under Galilean transformations?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

This two questions: [Vectors under Galilean transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/548013/vectors-under-galilean-transformation) and [Galilean transformations of velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/423410/galilean-transformations-of-velocity) seem to tackle the issue but one was closed and the latter did not refer to vectors.

To me a vector is some kind of oriented quantity that has preserves a definite magnitude and direction under some specific linear transformations.

A clear example are 4-vectors in special relativity. These objects have the following properties: a magnitude defined as
$$a^\mu a_\mu\tag{1}\label{eq:1}$$
and an orientation (angles) with respect to other vectors
$$b^\mu a_\mu\;, \tag{2}\label{eq:2} $$
where $a^\mu,b^\mu$ are 4-vectors in Minkowski space. Properties \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2} are invariants under Lorentz transformations and rotations, so these objects respect the definition of vector.

Now we could do the same analogy in classical mechanics, two 3D vectors $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ preserve their magnitude
$$|A|^2=\mathbf A\cdot \mathbf A=A^iA_i\tag{3}\label{eq:3}$$
and orientation
$$\mathbf A\cdot \mathbf B=A^iB_i=|A||B|\cos \theta\tag{4}\label{eq:4}$$
under rotations. But when it comes to Galilean boosts $\mathbf r\to \mathbf r'=\mathbf r-\mathbf V t$, for some speed $\mathbf V$ and time $t$. Quantities \eqref{eq:3} and \eqref{eq:4}  are not invariant as the speed of a particle $\mathbf v$ can become $\mathbf v'=0$ in a different frame. The only vector that seems to preserve its absolute value \eqref{eq:3} is the acceleration. So what are vectors in classical mechanics any way?

The question [Galilean transformations of velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/423410/galilean-transformations-of-velocity) seems to indicate that the right vectors that preserve \eqref{eq:3} and \eqref{eq:4} are not any traditional vectors (velocity, position,...), but differences between traditional vectors (example, two positions $\mathbf r_1$ and $\mathbf r_2$ preserve $|\Delta \mathbf r|^2=|\mathbf r_2-\mathbf r_1|^2=|\mathbf r_2'-\mathbf r_1'|^2$). Only relative vectors conserve \eqref{eq:3} and \eqref{eq:4}.

Is this the right way to define vectors under Galilean transformations?

Comment: Why do you think there should be only one right way? Can’t there be multiple valid ways, perhaps with different applications and benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Absolute positions and velocities are not invariant under Galilean transformations, but the magnitudes of relative positions and velocities *are* invariant.

By contrast, absolute time *is* invariant under Galilean transformations because the $t$ coordinate does not change.

Comment: I think that was surprises me is that special relativity does not require that additional restriction of only applying to relative vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Rethinking this, I have come to an answer.

In special relativity, spatial translations that does not conserve either (1) or (2) for all $a^\mu$ and $b^\mu$. But (1) or (2) are conserved as long as we are talking about relative positions, velocities and so on.
Special relativity just has this interesting notion that $a^\mu a_\mu$ is conserved under Lorentz's boost while Galilean boosts do not conserve $|\mathbf{A}|^2$, for classical $\mathbf{A}\neq \ddot{\mathbf{r}}$. Nevertheless conditions (1), (2), (3) and (4 are always conserved for relative vectors (under the appropriate transformation).

A better definition for vectors in physics would specify that a vector are those that conserve their relative quantities (like norm and relative angles) under a given transformation.